# How to duplicate the tab on QTabWidget using a list of elements?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I would to use this page created via QtDesigner and create as many tabs as there are elements in a predetermined list.
All the tabs will have the same composition and the name of each tab will be the element of the list.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

"""

```
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(577, 446)
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Dialog)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName("verticalLayout_5")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(Dialog)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.tab)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.tabWidget)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "TextLabel"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("Dialog", "Tab 1"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    if not QApplication.instance():
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    else:
        app = QApplication.instance()
    
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

    """ What I want to do"""
    #for element in list:
        #create tab in tabview as the one opening
        #tab.setTitle(element)
```

"""

Comment: Study the code above and try to understand what it does to create a single tab, then try to reproduce it. But, in any case, don't do it from that file, as manually editing pyuic files is considered bad practice and can result in problems: follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) instead.

Comment: Design custom widget and instantiate it N times